# How to draw a chart from one array of data and make labels on the chart from another array of data? Highcharts v.4.0.4

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I am drawing a chart with highcharts v.4.0.4.

Here is the chart I have at the moment:
http://jsfiddle.net/paulius_m/vvkf4g6q/1/

JavaScript part (the same as in jsfiddle):

```
$(function () {
    $('#chart').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'spline'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Groups'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: ''
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ["2014-08","2014-09","2014-10","2014-11"]
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            showEmpty: false,
            labels: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return null;
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: ''
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
            pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.0f}</b></td></tr>',
            footerFormat: '</table>',
            shared: true,
            useHTML: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                pointPadding: 0.2,
                borderWidth: 0
            }
        },
        series: [
            {"name":"User 11","data":[161,166,129,0],"user_name":"1","user_surname":"1","transformation_ratio":"1.14","data_transformed":[141,145,113,0]},
            {"name":"User 12","data":[0,0,0,0],"user_name":"1","user_surname":"2","transformation_ratio":"0.00","data_transformed":[0,0,0,0]},
            {"name":"User 13","data":[1,21,133,0],"user_name":"1","user_surname":"3","transformation_ratio":"0.39","data_transformed":[2,53,341,0]},
            {"name":"User 14","data":[2,3,1,0],"user_name":"1","user_surname":"4","transformation_ratio":"0.02","data_transformed":[100,150,50,0]}
            ]
    });
});
```

The problem is that the chart is drawn according to "data" of "series". I need it to be drawn according to "data_transformed" of "series". However, the labels of the chart must be made of the data from "data" of "series". How can I achieve this?

Comment: I solved the problem by changing the structure of "series" data and changing the "tooltip" part. The complete solution is here: http://jsfiddle.net/paulius_m/vvkf4g6q/3/ However,I believe that the problem could be solved in another way as well. The way avoiding modifications of structure of existing "series" data should also exists. However,I am perfectly fine with what I just came to. If somebody would not be able to change the structure of series then the answer of Sebastian Bochan should be considered. I accept the answer of Sebastian as it would be correct if "series" would stay as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need any loop which will map your data to correct format.